# Column is taking more space than required in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-card

I am trying to build a page view which is in a column. The page view will hold cards. i want the size of the page view to be dynamic to it's content i.e the card, but i am unable to achieve that. Apparently the column in the card  is taking up more space than required. I have checked it with flutter inspector and i can't understand why. Any help would be appreciated.
Here is the code.

```
import 'package:cricket_app/util/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_view_indicators/circle_page_indicator.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  PageController _controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );
  final _currentPageNotifier = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  final double _cardHeight = 200.0;
  final double _teamIconSize = 50.0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: primaryColor,
        elevation: 0,
        // flexibleSpace: Container(
        //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //       gradient: LinearGradient(
        //           begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        //           end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        //           colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.blue])),
        // ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "CRICKET APP",
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Flexible(
                  child: PageView(
                    controller: _controller,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      _buildMatchCard(context, _teamIconSize),
                      _buildMatchCard(context, _teamIconSize),
                      _buildMatchCard(context, _teamIconSize),
                    ],
                    onPageChanged: (int index) {
                      _currentPageNotifier.value = index;
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                CirclePageIndicator(
                  dotColor: primaryColor,
                  selectedDotColor: accentColor,
                  itemCount: 3,
                  selectedSize: 10.0,
                  currentPageNotifier: _currentPageNotifier,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                "News Section",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMatchCard(BuildContext context, double _teamIconSize) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      elevation: 2.0,
      color: darkGreyColor,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0),
              child: Text(
                "European Cricket Series, Stockholm, 11th Match",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Text(
                "04:00 PM 22-Oct at Rajiv Ghandhi Stadium, Hyderabad",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/icons/appIcon.jpg',
                            height: _teamIconSize,
                            width: _teamIconSize,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "WI",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "250/8",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            Text("50 Over")
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      "Live",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          color: Colors.red,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      width: 20.0,
                      height: 20.0,
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: accentColor,
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        "VS",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      )),
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 3.0, 10.0, 3.0),
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text("56"),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 5.0,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 3.0, 10.0, 3.0),
                          color: Colors.red,
                          child: Text("56"),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                      child: Text("Fav - IND"),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              "250/8",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                            Text("50 Over")
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset(
                          'assets/icons/appIcon.jpg',
                          height: _teamIconSize,
                          width: _teamIconSize,
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "WI",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 18.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Text(
                "INDIA needs 126 runs in 155 balls to win",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: you can constraint column size to the minimum by doing this 
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min

Comment: @ANUPSAJJAN This is not working. could you copy the code in a test project and see what is going on ? I have been stuck on this for days now.

Comment: can you check the answer I posted? Let me know if it helps?

Answer (score 10):

You should set appropriate **mainAxisSize** according to [oficial docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

> The height of the Column is determined by the mainAxisSize property. If the mainAxisSize property is MainAxisSize.max, then the height of the Column is the max height of the incoming constraints. If the mainAxisSize property is MainAxisSize.min, then the height of the Column is the sum of heights of the children (subject to the incoming constraints

```
...
child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.  //MIN or MAX
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
...
```

Comment: It is not working. I set the MainAxisSize to min for the main column of the card but the problem still remains.  I think the problem might be that i might have made the view more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is PageView. PageView will try to get all height as much as possible. So you can't use it without specifying a predefined height. Either you can determine the height of your card well before building pageView or give a hardcoded height, which can be bad considering the responsive nature of the app.

If you use pageview without mentioning any constraint to its height, it will try to grab the whole screen height if possible. So here is a workaround to your problem. You can modify it as per your requirements.

[image: Solution]

Wrap your pageview inside IndexedStack and container widget and give a height, which determines the size of your Pageview.

```
IndexedStack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 280,
                child: PageView( . . . ) ) ] )
```

So its not the problem of your buildCard method, its pageview which is taking height irrespective of the size of your card.

```
import 'package:cricket_app/util/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:page_view_indicators/circle_page_indicator.dart';

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<App> {
  PageController _controller = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
  );
  final _currentPageNotifier = ValueNotifier<int>(0);
  final double _cardHeight = 200.0;
  final double _teamIconSize = 50.0;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white70,
        elevation: 0,
        // flexibleSpace: Container(
        //   decoration: BoxDecoration(
        //       gradient: LinearGradient(
        //           begin: Alignment.topLeft,
        //           end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        //           colors: <Color>[Colors.red, Colors.blue])),
        // ),
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "CRICKET APP",
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          IndexedStack(
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 280,
                child: PageView(
                  controller: _controller,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildMatchCard(context, _teamIconSize),
                    _buildMatchCard(context, _teamIconSize),
                    _buildMatchCard(context, _teamIconSize),
                  ],
                  onPageChanged: (int index) {
                    _currentPageNotifier.value = index;
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                  child: Text(
                "News Section",
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
              )),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildMatchCard(BuildContext context, double _teamIconSize) {
    return Card(
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      elevation: 2.0,
      color: Colors.cyan,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
//        child: Text("das"),
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 10.0, 5.0, 0),
            child: Text(
              "European Cricket Series, Stockholm, 11th Match",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 18.0,
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Text(
              "04:00 PM 22-Oct at Rajiv Ghandhi Stadium, Hyderabad",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/img my hello bye.png',
                          height: _teamIconSize,
                          width: _teamIconSize,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "WI",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "250/8",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        Text("50 Over")
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    "Live",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 20.0,
                    height: 20.0,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, bottom: 5.0),
                    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      "VS",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                    )),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 3.0, 10.0, 3.0),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Text("56"),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 5.0,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 3.0, 10.0, 3.0),
                        color: Colors.red,
                        child: Text("56"),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                    child: Text("Fav - IND"),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          "250/8",
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, color: Colors.black),
                        ),
                        Text("50 Over")
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        'assets/images/img my hello bye.png',
                        height: _teamIconSize,
                        width: _teamIconSize,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10.0,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        "WI",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 18.0,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Text(
              "INDIA needs 126 runs in 155 balls to win",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for replying. This is what i had done earlier but my goal was to make to view totally dynamic/ fluid. So i guess there is no way to do that . the one thing that could help is if i could change the font size of the card content when it overflows. then i can give hard-coded height to the card.